# Read db.StringListProperty from ndb

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I have a DB model in AppEngine that looks something like this:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
  my_list = db.StringListProperty()
```

There are entities written to datastore with this data populated, I can pull them out via DB and I see the in the entity viewer.  I've been working to migrate to NDB, so the migrated model is:

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):
  my_list = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
```

But when I get entities out of datastore, `my_list` is never populated.  Is there some trick to retrieving these entities?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have 50 rep yet so I can't ask in a comment, but if you have copy-pasted your code across, I am pretty sure your issue is that you are still prefixing with "db"

It should be

```
my_list = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
```

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/db_to_ndb#properties

We also try to keep our indexes as minimal as possible to lower datastore write costs, so adding indexed=False to it is what we always do.

```
my_list = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True, indexed=False)
```

If that still isn't working, you may need an intermediary function to grab the DB version, and rewrite it to an NDB version, but as far as I know, that shouldn't be necessary (I haven't done a DB->NDB migration myself)

> In case you wondered, despite the different APIs, NDB and the old ext.db package write exactly the same data to the Datastore. That means you don’t have to do any conversion to your datastore, and you can happily mix and match NDB and ext.db code, as long as the schema you use is equivalent. You can even convert between ext.db and NDB keys using ndb.Key.from_old_key() and key.to_old_key().

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it was a transposition/sanitation error.  Verified that code actually uses "ndb". Migrating the data via a mapreduce job may be the eventual answer, once I get to the point where that's feasible.